# JavaScript onkeyup Exception

Tags: javascript

I have tried the below code but it is showing an exception while key up event occurs.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Card Number :
    <asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" MaxLength="4"  Width="40px" onkeyup="MoveCorsor(this, 'Text2');"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Text2" runat="server" MaxLength="4" onkeyup="MoveCorsor(this, 'Text3');" Width="40px"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Text3" runat="server" MaxLength="4" onkeyup="MoveCorsor(this, 'Text4');" Width="40px"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Text4" runat="server" MaxLength="4" Width="40px"/>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MoveCursor(FromTextBox, ToTextBox)
        {
            var length = FromTextBox.value.length;
            var maxLength = FromTextBox.getAttribute("MaxLength");
            if(length==maxLength)
            {
                document.getElementById(ToTextBox).focus();
            }
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Please format your code using the `{}` button

Comment: Hi @Arya Chuodhury - I have posted answer. Check it and let me know if still you get  any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake - Wrong spelling while calling onkeyup() function in all textboxes.
Ex.

```
onkeyup="MoveCorsor(this, 'Text3');"
```

Just check below code - it's working properly in my system.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function MoveCursor(FromTextBox, ToTextBox)
            {
                var length = FromTextBox.value.length;
                var maxLength = FromTextBox.getAttribute("MaxLength");
                if(length==maxLength)
                {
                    document.getElementById(ToTextBox).focus();
                }
            }

    </script>

    <body>

    <input type="text" ID="Text1" runat="server" MaxLength="4"  Width="40px" onkeyup="MoveCursor(this, 'Text2');"/>
    <input type="text" ID="Text2" runat="server" MaxLength="4" onkeyup="MoveCursor(this, 'Text3');" Width="40px"/>
    <input type="text" ID="Text3" runat="server" MaxLength="4" onkeyup="MoveCursor(this, 'Text4');" Width="40px"/>  
    <input type="text" ID="Text4" runat="server" MaxLength="4" Width="40px"/>

    </body>
    </html>
```